# Script error: overflow: 'CInt' - VBScript

Tags: vbscript

When adding the counter next number above 5 digits:
there is overflow.

Error is not if it is 5 digits.

I used VBScript:

```
Counter = CInt (Counter) + CInt (Qty)
```

I would like to use 7 digits in the numerator.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: If your *Counter* isn't a floating-point number, you should use [`CLng()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck4c5842%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @GeniuSBraiN while I agree it depends how big your numbers are going to be. OP mentions 7 digits so `Long` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure this has been answered before...

Overflow Errors are probably the easiest errors to correct in VBScript. It's telling you that the current data type cannot contain the value. Because you are using `CInt()` to explicitly define you are working with `Integer` data type you have the following restriction.

> <sup>From [MSDN - VBScript Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)</sup>
> ***Integer**
>
> Contains integer in the range -32,768 to 32,767.*

This doesn't give you a lot of wiggle room, so instead use `Long` or `Double` *(if working with floating point numbers or it's just too big for `Long`)*

> <sup>From [MSDN - VBScript Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)</sup>
> ***Long**
>
> Contains integer in the range -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.*
>
> ***Double**
>
> Contains a double-precision, floating-point number in the range -1.79769313486232E308 to -4.94065645841247E-324 for negative values; 4.94065645841247E-324 to 1.79769313486232E308 for positive values.*

the equivalent function for converting to `Long` is `Clng()` and for `Double` is `CDbl()`.

---

#### Useful Links

- [Cint overflow error when value exceeds 100,000+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32916791/692942)
- [cint overflow error in my VB script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5652264/692942)
- [Classic ASP App CINT failure - twitpocalypse v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195390/classic-asp-app-cint-failure-twitpocalypse-v2) *(Still VBScript so still relevant)*

Comment: The OP didn't mention that he's working with floating-point numbers, so probably `Long` should be used instead of `Double`

Comment: @GeniuSBraiN Absolutely right, I didn't read the code just saw it was a Overflow Error on an Integer. If they are using variables like `Counter` doubt it will be floating point. There are occasions though when even `Long` isn't enough.